# How do I get dimensions from a CloudinaryPreloadedFile

Tags: cloudinary

I need to save the dimensions of my images in my database to help me render images in a pinterest style gallery format.

I use to have this method:

```
def update_asset_attributes
  if image.present? && image_changed?
    ap image.file
    self.image_content_type = image.file.content_type
    self.image_file_size = image.file.size
    self.image_width, self.image_height = `identify -format "%wx%h" #{image.file.path}`.split(/x/)
  end
end
```

But now it says: `NoMethodError - undefined method content_type for #<Cloudinary::CarrierWave::PreloadedCloudinaryFile:0x007f9834d81840>:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudinaryPreloadedFile doesn't have this information at the moment. You can either -

1. Pass the information by yourself from the javascript code to the server (you can use the cloudinarydone callback data.result object).
2. Use the [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) gem.
3. If the number of images uploaded per hour are small, you can use the [Admin API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#details_of_a_single_resource) to get the resource's information given it's public_id.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using CarrierWave. Does this open up any other options?

Comment: The answer above applies to the case where CarrierWave is used.

Comment: Okay I'm going with option #1. Thanks!